# How can I find a value in all fields using SOSL?

Tags: apex, sosl

I want to find if any records have a value "Test123"
How could I do this using SOSL and Apex?

I tried this:

```
List<List<SObject>> l = [FIND 'test123' limit 10];
```

But it throws an error:

> Entities should be explictly specified in SOSL call in Apex

Do I need to specify specific objects in SOSL query or is there a way to search through all objects in an organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the limitation here applies only to Apex. You can use, for example, the Query tab in Developer Console to find all records this way, or use the API. In theory, you could even set up an `HttpRequest` to call the API directly and parse the results you get back, though this won't work in some contexts. Aside from that, you can use `Database.search` and build a dynamic query based on `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` if you'd like. So, depending on your use case, you have at least a few options available.

Answer (score 0):

When you use it in Apex, the RETURNING clause is not optional.
When you use it in Query Editor of the Dev console this is optional.
So you need to specify the RETURNING clause with the list of objects that you would like to search.